# How can i use redirection for my URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, web-config

How can i use redirection for my URL in wordpress?

MY URL is:

> mydomain.com/blog/why-logos-should-be-simple/

Want to redirect on:

> mydomain.com/why-logos-should-be-simple/

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Wordpress Multisite, by default the primary site uses /blog in its URLs. There are ways to fix this, elsewhere answered https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/remove-the-blog-slug-from-wordpress-multisite-root-node